# How to join two Kafka streams and produce the result in a topic with Avro values

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I've got two Kafka Streams with keys in `String` and values in `Avro` format which I have created using KSQL.

Here's the first one:

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED STREAM_1; 
Type                 : STREAM
Key field            : IDUSER
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Key format           : STRING
Value format         : AVRO
Kafka output topic   : STREAM_1 (partitions: 4, replication: 1)

 Field                      | Type
--------------------------------------------------------
 ROWTIME                    | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY                     | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 FIRSTNAME                  | VARCHAR(STRING)
 LASTNAME                   | VARCHAR(STRING)
 IDUSER                     | VARCHAR(STRING)
```

and the second one:

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED STREAM_2;
Type                 : STREAM
Key field            : IDUSER
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Key format           : STRING
Value format         : AVRO
Kafka output topic   : STREAM_2 (partitions: 4, replication: 1)

 Field                      | Type
--------------------------------------------------------
 ROWTIME                    | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY                     | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 USERNAME                   | VARCHAR(STRING)
 IDUSER                     | VARCHAR(STRING)
 DEVICE                     | VARCHAR(STRING)
```

The desired output should include `IDUSER`, `LASTNAME`, `DEVICE` and `USERNAME`.

I want to `left join` these streams (on `IDUSER`) using Streams API and write the output into a kafka topic.

To do so, I've tried the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();

    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "kafka-strteams");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT_CONFIG, "localhost:2181");
    streamsConfiguration.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");

    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
    streamsConfiguration.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
    final Serde<GenericRecord> genericAvroSerde = new GenericAvroSerde();


    boolean isKeySerde = false;
    genericAvroSerde.configure(Collections.singletonMap(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081"), isKeySerde);

    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    KStream<String, GenericRecord> left = builder.stream("STREAM_1");
    KStream<String, GenericRecord> right = builder.stram("STREAM_2");

    // Java 8+ example, using lambda expressions
    KStream<String, GenericRecord> joined = left.leftJoin(right,
        (leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue, /* ValueJoiner */
        JoinWindows.of(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5)),
        Joined.with(
          stringSerde, /* key */
          genericAvroSerde,   /* left value */
          genericAvroSerde)  /* right value */
      );
    joined.to(stringSerde, genericAvroSerde, "streams-output-testing");

    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfiguration);
    streams.cleanUp();
    streams.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
}
```

However,

```
KStream<String, GenericRecord> joined = ...
```

throws an error on my IDE:

```
incompatible types: inference variable VR has incompatible bounds
```

When I try to use a `String` `Serde` for both keys and values, it works but the data is not that readable from `kafka-console-consumer`. What I want to do is to produce the data in AVRO format in order to be able to read them off using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first guess is that you are returning a `String` from the join operation, whereas your code expects a `GenericRecord` as the result:

```java
KStream<String, GenericRecord> joined = left.leftJoin(right,
    (leftValue, rightValue) -> "left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue, ...)
```

Note how `joined` has type `KStream<String, GenericRecord>`, i.e. the value has type `GenericRecord`, but the join output is computed via `"left=" + leftValue + ", right=" + rightValue`, which has type `String`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you suggest a workaround? How can I instantiate a GenericRecord from a join so that in the very end a value in AVRO format is produced?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the actual fields for both streams in order to get a taste of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Take a look at the Avro API on how to instantiate a GenericRecord.  This step is not specific to Kafka Streams.  I'd suggest to create a separate question for this on SO if need be.

Comment: I'll have a look into avro API. A last question which will make my life easier when constructing the `GenericRecord`. What will `leftValue` and `rightValue` normally contain? In this particular case will `leftValue` contain `FIRSTNAME`, `LASTNAME` and `rightValue` `USERNAME` and `DEVICE`?

Comment: leftValue will be the GenericRecord pojo from the left side of the join (`STREAM_1`), rightValue will be the GenericRecord pojo from the right side (`STREAM_2`).

Comment: See the API of GenericRecord (in Avro) on how to access your fields. For example, you can do `leftValue.get("FIRSTNAME")`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting value into string you can directly return value.
For example :

```
KStream joined = left.leftJoin(right,
(leftValue, rightValue) -> { return rightValue});
```